# Create a new customer group - Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In Prestahop. I need to create a new Customer Group called: SPECIAL COSTUMERS. I don't want these customers to see prices not to make any payment. I just want them to be able to sent me a Product List of what they need.

I need to get this:

The buyers whose **are not SPECIAL COSTUMERS** will: :

- be able to see product prices
- be able to add products to the cart
- be able to complete the checkout process including the payment

The buyers whose **are SPECIAL COSTUMERS** will:

- **not** see product prices
- be able to add products to the cart
- complete the checkout process BUT NOT ANY PAYMENT
- Then the administrator will get a notification with the product list selected for the customer.

How can I get this? Is there any module for this? Will I need to create a custom code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new group with no access to prices in BackOffice Group page. On this page you can also remove access to payment modules.

Finally you can create a custom payment module, which will create an order with a custom state as "wish list" for example and send you a notification. Your module shall extends `PaymentModule` class. You can have a look at `bankwire` module which is quite simple to understand.

Comment: I set the group to "no access to prices" but then this client is not be able to add products to the cart to make the order. The button "add to cart" is removed.

Comment: Am I missing something here?

Comment: No you're not, Prestashop is a pain for this kind of configuration. You'll have to set "access to prices" to true and edit every template files that contain a price to hide it manually from your customer depending on their group.

Comment: Ok, I see, can you just point me one of these template file (its location) so that I can figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: For example "/themes/your_theme/product.tpl". Good luck, it will be tedious task ;). You'll also have to hide prices in module blockcart, on the cart page and order pages... and other templates I can't think of.